# Reading gsettings from C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, gsettings

I need to programmatically get the value of com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor from gsettings in my C++ program. Is there any elegant way to do this, instead of calling gsettings binary and parsing it's output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a C++ binding to gsettings in glibmm. With it, reading a value from a schema can be done as shown below. Note that I do not have an Ubuntu system on which to test this, so specifics rely on a short look into the documentation that told me `scale-factor` is an integral value. With this in mind:

```
#include <giomm/settings.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Settings> s = Gio::Settings::create("com.ubuntu.user-interface");
  int i = s->get_int("scale-factor");

  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

See also [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1Settings.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can't post a comment to Wintermute answer because of low reputation so I post it here.

Newbe, like me, could have problem including `<giomm/settings.h>` (not found): a solution is to append to gcc compile command `` `pkg-config --cflags --libs glibmm-2.4 giomm-2.4` `` (with backticks)

> If your source file is `program.cc`, you can compile it with:
>
> `` g++ program.cc -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs glibmm-2.4 giomm-2.4` ``

From [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/)